# How can I enforce running grunt before git push?

Tags: git, gruntjs

I am using grunt to create production ready files from my dev files and git for source control and pushing to prod server. It works nice if a person who pushes files uses it properly (run `grunt` then `git push`).

The problem is that sometimes people forgot and just push. This does not create errors in app per se, but does not add new functionality to the project (which creates a confusion). I am trying to find a way how can I enforce running grunt before git push. So when I just run git push, it tells me: Hey you forgot to run grunt!

Currently the only theoretical way I came up with is to have increments in prod build files and run git pre-commit hook to compare these numbers and discard commits that has the same numbers. Is there any problem with this idea? Is there a better idea?

Comment: Can't the production server be the one running grunt with a hook?

Comment: @IdanArye this is certainly possible. But I would rather keep my production server with the minimum needed installation.

Comment: Also server side hook, but maybe requires less tooling: You could refuse pushes which doesn't contain the compiled assets. (or anything your generates.)

Comment: In the line of what you already suggest to do: if you can get to know that grunt has not been executed git pre-push  hook might be useful. If grunt has not been executed you can abort the push and output a message. The hook receives the SHA of the commit so you can inspect the changes and content.

Comment: Not sure that this answers your question, but Travis CI could help: http://travis-ci.org. grunt-githooks might also be useful: http://npmjs.com/package/grunt-githooks.

Answer (score 1):

We could imagine enforcing code review (using for example [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/)): if the committer forget, the reviewer might notice it.

However, what about using another tool to push to prod? Having a deployer tool responsible for pushing from the repo to the prod servers would surely be more flexible than Git.

What about for example a Jenkins server which could run every hour (or on-demand) to fetch the git repo, run Grunt, and push on the prod server?